# Create an array of possible characters in search string

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, special-characters, diacritics

I'm trying to create an array of possible characters after a user submits a search.

If I search for the user `Draven` I'd like my array to look like this (and any other characters I'm missing)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dräven
    [1] => Dr&auml;ven
    [2] => Dr&aUML;ven
    [3] => Draven
)
```

Is there a simple (short) way of doing this?
Only thing I've come up with is a function that is 500 lines long and that's only half the characters I need.

Comment: if you keep it all in utf8 there should be no need for this

Comment: but what are you trying to achieve? maybe you don't need that function. could you show us the fragment of code where you plan to use this code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could approach this another way. Rather than converting the user input into every possible variant and comparing, remove the diacritics from your search space and compare.

```
// Normalise data (remove accent marks)
// This requires the intl extension
// On debian: apt-get install php5-intl
$data = normalizer_normalize($data);
```

If you do this you might need to keep two lots of data - one as the original unconverted data and again normalised that you use as your search space.